# My self-defined queue not printing properly

Tags: python, class

I'm currently doing a class assignment to create a Class Queue using linked list. My code is as follows:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None
    self.prev = None
class Queue:
def __init__(self):
    self.front = None
    self.rear = None
def enqueue(self, value):
    newNode = Node(value)
    if self.rear is None:
        self.front = newNode
        self.rear = self.front
    else:
        self.rear.next = newNode
        self.rear.next.prev = self.rear
        self.rear = self.rear.next
def dequeue(self):
    if self.front is None:
        return None
    else:
        to_remove = self.front.data
        self.front = self.front.next
        self.front.prev = None
        return to_remove

def printQueue(self):
    print('The elements in the queue are ')
    element = self.front
    while element is not None:
        print(element, end = "")
        element = element.next
myqueue = Queue()
for i in range(21):
   if i % 3 == 0:
      myqueue.enqueue(i)
   elif i % 5 == 0:
      myqueue.dequeue()
myqueue.printQueue()
```

But when I tried printing, it comes up like this:

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x000001EB465D8048><__main__.Node object at 0x000001EB465D8128><__main__.Node object at 0x000001EB465D8080><__main__.Node object at 0x000001EB465D80F0>
```

I searched on the internet and tried to change my code but it still shows up the same. I don't understand why though.

Comment: These are not errors but the objects. Try printing `element.data` instead

Answer (score 2):

As the comment says, and I modified your questions itself, too. You have to print the value of the objects, not the objects themselves. It's not an error, just a little confusion on your part.

Answer (score 1):

When you print out element you print the location of the object's memory.

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x000001EB465D8048><__main__.Node object at 0x000001EB465D8128><__main__.Node object at 0x000001EB465D8080><__main__.Node object at 0x000001EB465D80F0>
```

The hexadecimal values are addresses.

In order to access the value present at these locations use `element.data` instead of `element`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that is not an error. Your `printQueue` function iterates the elements and prints each element. The type of each element is `Node`.
For example, your output contains the representation of the nodes:
The object below is a single node, defined in the `__main__` function. Its type is `Node Object` and its memory address is `0x000001EB465D8048`

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x000001EB465D8048>
```

To print a user friendly version of each node, the node class needs to override the `__str__` method.

For example, if you would modify your `Node` class to have the following structure, then you could just use `print(element, end = "\n")` inside your `printQueue` method.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)
```

The output then would be

```
The elements in the queue are 
9
12
15
18
```

Furthermore, while not directly related to your question, it's tangential enough that you might find it helpful. Python objects have both a `__str__` and a `__repr__`method. 
Simply put, the `__str__` is used to represent the readable form of your object, and the `__repr__` the unambiguous representation.

For more information on those 2 methods, [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) does a good job at explaining them.